# Using Reflection to get property from field

Tags: c#

I have these classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar bar;
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<int> Something { get; set; }
    public string Else { get; set; }
}
```

I have a lot of classes like `Foo`. They all contain exactly one field. This field, `Bar` in my example, will be a different type of object every time, it doesn't have to be of type `Bar`. Whatever object it is (`Bar` or otherwise), this field will always be an object that has two properties, `Something` and `Else`.

My challenge: given any object that's like Foo (with one Field that holds two properties), get the value of the two properties. Given this method:

```
public void DoStuff(object myObject)
{
    var asdf = myObject.GetType().GetFields().First();
}
```

I can get the FieldInfo for Bar. What I'm looking for is the values of `Something` and `Else`. The names of these properties never change. Whatever the type is of the Field, it will always have two properties named `Something` and `Else` that will be of the same type.

Sadly, my problem involves auto generated code, and there are no shared interfaces or base types I can easily use.

Comment: And I assume the type of `Something` is always a `List<int>` and `Else` is always a `string`?

Comment: @Sweeper That is correct. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this code you can retrieve the `PropertyInfo`s for the `Something` and for the `Else` property:

```cs
Foo myObject = new Foo { bar = new Bar() };

// the FieldInfo for Foo.bar
var barField = myObject.GetType().GetFields().First();

// the Bar instance, i.e. myObject.bar
var barValue = barField.GetValue(myObject);

var somethingProperty = barField.FieldType.GetProperty("Something", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
var elseProperty = barField.FieldType.GetProperty("Else", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

as *PsiHamster* noted, you can then use [`GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0) and [`SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=net-5.0) to retrieve and set the values of `somethingProperty` and `elseProperty` like this:

```cs
// get the value
var somethingValue = somethingProperty.GetValue(barValue);

// set the value
somethingProperty.SetValue(barValue, new List<int>());
```

Comment: Actually property supports `GetValue()` method, so you don't need to Invoke Methods by yourself

Comment: Thanks, this works brilliant. Now I don't have to write over a 1000 lines of Automapper configuration. Thank you so much.

Comment: @yesman Good to hear that it helps. If you're actually using this in production, please absolutely consider caching the `FieldInfo` and the `PropertyInfo`s so that you're not calling `GetFields()` and `GetProperty()` for every object.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Get Bar FieldInfo
var barFieldInfo = myObject.GetType().GetFields().First();

// Get all public instance properties info
var barProps = barFieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

// Get Something and Else properties info
var smthPropInfo = barProps.First(prop => prop.Name == nameof(Bar.Something));
var elsePropInfo = barProps.First(prop => prop.Name == nameof(Bar.Else));

// Get values
var bar = barFieldInfo.GetValue(myObject);
var smth = smthPropInfo.GetValue(bar);
var else = elsePropInfo.GetValue(bar);
```